Springboot 3.2 log file not written
i have a spring boot application running in tomcat. To load the application properties I use the following construct:
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:/opt/tomcat/latest/conf/application.properties")
class JpaConfig {
}

In the application.properties file I have the following logging options:
logging.file.path=/opt/tomcat/latest/logs
logging.file.name=/opt/tomcat/latest/logs/mylog.log
logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug
logging.level.com.myapp=debug

My problem is that the log file mylog.log is not being created when the application starts. I thought that it is a problem of permissions but the logs folder has the same owner and group as the springboot application.
I tried also to build the properties directly when the application runs in code, but that did not change anything:
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val springApplication = SpringApplication(DemoApplication::class.java)
    val properties = Properties()
    properties["logging.file.name"] = "/opt/tomcat/latest/logs/mylog.log"
    properties["logging.file.path"] = "/opt/tomcat/latest/logs/"
    properties["logging.level.org.springframework.web"] = "debug"
    properties["logging.level.com.myapp"] = "debug"
    springApplication.setDefaultProperties(properties)
    springApplication.run(*args)
 }

Other possible idea that I found on the web was to use logback-spring.xml. That I did not try. I hope that there is a simpler explanation and solution to this problem. What can still be wrong with my configuration ? Can I see somehow in some error log what happens when trying to create the log file ? I use ubuntu on my server.

According to the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/reference/features/logging.html#features.logging.file-output, your log file should be created by only included the property logging.file.name. Unsure if by specifying both cause confusion to Spring, but it is something to try.

I have tried to define only logging.file.name but still no file is created.

Here you have a simple demo (https://github.com/silver-mx/stackoverflow-demos/tree/main/demo-logging) that I created from https://start.spring.io/. I had to give permissions to /opt/tomcat/latest/logs/ in order to work. I also tried writing the log to a path under /tmp to discard permission issues.

I downloaded the example and tested with a local installation of tomcat. No logs were written.

I changed the deployment from war to external tomcat to jar with embedded tomcat and now the logs are written. So this is a issue related to the use of an external tomcat.
